# iOS :Sending Facebook Request

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I have sent facebook request.  Its working fine, but I am getting request(notification) only in iPhone facebook App, not in Facebook web application.  I want both Facebook native app and web application to receive notification. How can I do that?

```
#pragma Sending Facebook app request

- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
        NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *val =
        [[kv objectAtIndex:1]
         stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [params setObject:val forKey:[kv objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    return params;
}
- (void)sendRequest {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                        dataWithJSONObject:@{
                        @"social_karma": @"5",
                        @"badge_of_awesomeness": @"1"}
                        options:0
                        error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    NSString *giftStr = [[NSString alloc]
                         initWithData:jsonData
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   giftStr, @"data",
                                   nil];

    // Display the requests dialog
    [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
     title:nil
     parameters:params
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the send request callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Send button
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}

- (void)sendRequestClicked {
    // Filter and only show friends using iOS
    [self requestFriendsUsingDevice:@"iOS"];
}


- (void)sendRequest:(NSArray *) targeted {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                        dataWithJSONObject:@{
                        @"social_karma": @"5",
                        @"badge_of_awesomeness": @"1"}
                        options:0
                        error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"JSON error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
    NSString *giftStr = [[NSString alloc]
                         initWithData:jsonData
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableDictionary* params =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:giftStr, @"data",
     nil];

    // Filter and only show targeted friends
    if (targeted != nil && [targeted count] > 0) {
        NSString *selectIDsStr = [targeted componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        [params setObject:selectIDsStr forKey:@"suggestions"];
    }

    // Display the requests dialog
    [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
     title:nil
     parameters:params
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             // Error launching the dialog or sending request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 // User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 // Handle the send request callback
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     // User clicked the Cancel button
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     // User clicked the Send button
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}


- (void) requestFriendsUsingDevice:(NSString *)device {
    NSMutableArray *deviceFilteredFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                 parameters:[NSDictionary
                                             dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             @"id,devices", @"fields",
                                             nil]
                                 HTTPMethod:nil
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  // Get the result
                                  NSArray *resultData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                                  // Check we have data
                                  if ([resultData count] > 0) {
                                      // Loop through the friends returned
                                      for (NSDictionary *friendObject in resultData) {
                                          // Check if devices info available
                                          if ([friendObject objectForKey:@"devices"]) {
                                              NSArray *deviceData = [friendObject
                                                                     objectForKey:@"devices"];
                                              // Loop through list of devices
                                              for (NSDictionary *deviceObject in deviceData) {
                                                  // Check if there is a device match
                                                  if ([device isEqualToString:
                                                       [deviceObject objectForKey:@"os"]]) {
                                                      // If there is a match, add it to the list
                                                      [deviceFilteredFriends addObject:
                                                       [friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
                                                      break;
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                              // Send request
                              [self sendRequest:deviceFilteredFriends];
                          }];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider following points when you post in SO from now on 1)Use 'I', not 'i' when referencing yourself. 2) It seems you are not native english speaker, but please make sure to split sentences correctly and use '.' where due. 3) [This is how you format code in SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) 4) [Please don't use 'Hi', 'Thanks' etc tag lines in your post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

You can only get notifications on Facebook web application if your app has a Facebook Canvas app implemented.

> The invitable_friends API is only available for games that have a
> Facebook Canvas app implementation using version 2.0 of the Graph API.

[Check here the full documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.1)

> Canvas is a frame in which to put your app or game directly on
> Facebook.com on desktops and laptops.

[Details about Canvas](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas)

Note: In the documentation you will find "your game", they mean "your game or your app".