# iOS - Can't send Facebook requests

Tags: ios, facebook, request, fbwebdialogs

I currently have a problem with my iOS application because I don't seem to be able to send requests to people...
Here is the code that I have:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

if([FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] message:@"Join me." title:@"Invite" parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [FBSession activeSession]);
        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
        else {
            if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
            else if(result == FBWebDialogResultDialogCompleted)
                NSLog(@"Request: %@", resultURL);
            else
                NSLog(@"Error unknown.");
        }
    }];        
}
else {
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        if(session.isOpen) {
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                if(session.isOpen) {
                    [self showRequestForFacebook];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

<s>Every time I get a `Request: (null)`.</s> **I get a request ID but nothing on the account.** I looked at the sample in the Facebook SDK and I seem to have exactly the same. However, it works with the sample and not with my code.
Is there anything to change somewhere? Is it something on developers.facebook.com?

Edit: I forgot to say that in the same application I use a SLComposeViewController to share on Facebook and it works perfectly.

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Can you log your `FBSession activeSession` and make sure it's good first?

Comment: Here is the log: 
session: <FBSession: 0xae3ee90, state: FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 588630294501794, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0xae3f200>, expirationDate: 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, refreshDate: 2013-08-05 21:39:00 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
)>

Comment: Are you sure query is supposed to be anything other than null in this case? That's just showing the query part of the request string. Not sure that's the issue you're actually facing.

Comment: Well, for all I know it should be something yes; otherwise how do you know that a request has been sent? Anyway, it doesn't work and I don't see why. Do I need to add permissions?

Comment: What permissions did you request with your auth request?

Comment: @[@"publish_actions"]

Comment: To be clear, you get publish_actions, you must first to a read permission request, then use that session to do a write permission request. Are you doing that?

Comment: Something like that: [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {if(session.isOpen) {
                [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                    if(session.isOpen) {
                        [self showRequestForFacebook];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];

Comment: To be clear, if you're getting "Request: (null)" that means you are in state FBWebDialogResultCompleted, which means you should have succeeded, regardless of whether or not the NSString result had a query part. But I'm not sure without seeing more code, etc.

Comment: I changed my post to show my whole function. Nothing more, nothing less. By the way, now I get a request ID. Just nothing on the account. :(

Comment: Did you check the account on Facebook website or on the Facebook App? If you check it on the website, then there is no issue in your code. The issue is "sending requests is only available for games/Apps that have a Facebook Canvas app implementation using version 2.0 of the Graph API." Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335575/ios-sending-facebook-request/25304544#25304544

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *query2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid, name, pic_square,is_app_user FROM user WHERE  is_app_user = 1 AND uid IN " @"(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"];

// Set up the query parameter
NSDictionary *queryParam2 = @{ @"q": query2 };
// Make the API request that uses FQL
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql" parameters:queryParam2  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                               id result,
                                                               NSError *error)
                                           {

                                            if (error) {

                                            } else {
                                            // NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                             // Get the friend data to display
                                             NSArray *friendInfo = (NSArray *) result[@"data"];
                                              NSLog(@"%@",friendInfo);
                                             self.data=friendInfo;

                                           [self constructDictionaryOfNumbers];
                                             // Show the friend details display

                                            }
                                           }];
```

}